# Exporting Spring Bean Service in OSGI- New Instance per Injection Call

Tags: osgi, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to export a spring bean as service using Spring's application context, I need to have them exported as "prototype" scope, but this is not possible due to OSGi Service registry caching the service as singleton.

Doing some research I came upon a [post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/269120/770471/#msg_770471) suggesting to use "session" scope to get around this issue. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-bean-scopes-request-session-global-session-example/) to get this working, but I am stuck with an issue that has to do with class loader not finding an interface.

Here's how I am declaring the bean

```
<osgi:service id="SimulationExporter" ref="simulationService" interface="org.geppetto.core.simulation.ISimulation"/>
<bean id="simulationService" scope="session" class="org.geppetto.simulation.SimulationService">
<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
```

When exporting the bean to another bundle, I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject is not visible from class loader
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:484)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:713)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:117)
```

The bundle importing the service bean has the dependency org.springframework.aop-3.0.0.RELEASE , and this has also being copied to the virgo repository. Any ideas why would the class loader not find that interface that it needs for scope "session"?

Answer (score 1):

Does your MANIFEST.MF include import packages for aop.scope? 
If you are using Apache Felix to generate it try adding something like this:

```
    <Import-Package>org.aopalliance.aop,org.springframework.aop,org.springframework.aop.scope,org.springframework.aop.framework,*</Import-Package>
```